# I got Too few positional arguments error flutter and I can't understand why?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi everyone my app was work will before two to days today when I run my app it gives me that following error :
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modal_bottom_sheet-0.2.0+1/lib/src/bottom_sheet.dart:295:43: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
_velocityTracker = VelocityTracker();
^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/velocity_tracker.dart:152:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
VelocityTracker(this.kind);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/fade_scale_transition.dart:148:29: Error: 'decelerateEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: decelerateEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:315:12: Error: 'decelerateEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
curve: decelerateEasing,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:321:29: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:326:29: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:335:35: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:355:35: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:402:12: Error: 'accelerateEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
curve: accelerateEasing,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:408:29: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:413:29: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:422:35: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/animations-1.1.1/lib/src/shared_axis_transition.dart:445:35: Error: 'standardEasing' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/curves.dart' and 'package:animations/src/utils/curves.dart'.
).chain(CurveTween(curve: standardEasing));
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I don't understand why this error is appear and how I fixed It .
any suggestions will appreciated

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/69. As a (temporary) workaround, you could downgrade flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open this file which is giving error:

`C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/modal_bottom_sheet-0.2.0+1/lib/src/bottom_sheet.dart:295:43:`

At line 295 fix the error by changing:

`_velocityTracker = VelocityTracker();`

into

`_velocityTracker = VelocityTracker(PointerDeviceKind.touch);`

This is a temporary work around. The issue will be fixed in next beta release.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similiar error after I updated my flutter version to 3.0.0. I updated the `modal_bottom_sheet` package in the pubspec.yaml file from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1. After this it worked for me also with flutter version 3.0.0.

```
modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
```

Don't forget to run `pub get` after the upgrade to the new version.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this in my pubspec.yaml file, so i just added:

```
modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
```

ran on terminal after:

```
flutter pub get
```

and we good to go...